# Adding excluded categories to existing excluded categories for Wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post category, "Events," which I would like to have excluded from all queries throughout my site. In addition, I will have additional categories to be excluded from my queries on certain pages. For instance, on the homepage I have a query where I would like to exclude an additional category of `19`.

In my functions I have this code which is excluding the "Events" category(ID of `3`):

```
// exclude events from queries
function exclude_category($query) {
  $query->set('cat', '-3');
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

This is working as expected, however on my homepage where I am trying to exclude an additional category(ID of `19`) the category is not being excluded. The `exclude_category` function from my `functions.php` file seems to override the `category__not_in` argument from the query on my homepage:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'        => array('post'),
  'posts_per_page'   => 3,
  'category__not_in' => 19
));
```

How can I modify the arguments of the homepage query(and elsewhere) to exclude both the "Events" category(which is being excluded in the `functions.php` file) and any additional categories I want to pass into the query arguments?

Comment: "... I am trying to exclude an additional category(ID of 19) the category is not being excluded", _how_ exactly are you trying to exclude this additional category? In the code you posted you're only excluding category 3, so please update it with the code you tried and didn't work so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: It's in the 2nd code snippet where I am excluding the additional category using the `category__not_in` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [category__not_in parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) also accepts an array of integers, so if you want to exclude multiple categories you can do this:

```
$categories_to_exclude = array(3);

if ( is_home() ) {
  $categories_to_exclude = array(3, 19);
}

$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'        => array('post'),
  'posts_per_page'   => 3,
  'category__not_in' => $categories_to_exclude
));
```

Likewise in your `exclude_category()` function you can pass multiple categories to the `cat` parameters, separated by comma:

```
// exclude events from queries
function exclude_category($query) {
  $categories_to_exclude = '-3';

  // You might not need this but I added it as an example:
  //
  // We're viewing the homepage, exclude category 19 too
  if ( is_home() ) {
    $categories_to_exclude .= ', -19';
  }

  $query->set('cat', $categories_to_exclude);
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

More details: [WP_Query - Category Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).

Comment: The problem is that I only want category `3` to be excluded from every query. But then I will have various other queries throughout the site with different additional excluded categories, so I am looking for a way to exclude `3` from all queries but then be able to add additional excluded categories on a per-query basis

Comment: Well, here I'd use specific [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to change the IDs of the categories I want to exclude according to a specific situation. For example: to also exclude ID 19 only when viewing the homepage, I'd use either [is_home()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Main_Page) or [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page) (the pick depends on how the theme works). See the updated answer for details.

Comment: As for how to dynamically update the other queries, well, that depends on the specific conditions (which you didn't mention in your question.)